# window.open(window.parent) possible?

Tags: javascript, window.open, window.parent

I have a button and when the user clicks the button this code is triggered...

```
window.open('','','width=640,height=480,resizeable,scrollbars');
```

which opens a new window. What I want displayed is the the current page in that new window so I tried..

```
window.open('window.parent.getElementById("printPage")','','width=640,height=480,resizeable,scrollbars');
```

but all it says is that the file is not found :(

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, if this is possible and how do i fix it?

Thanks,
J

Comment: Have you tried removing the quotes around your first parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.location` should give you the current windows location, so:

```
window.open(window.location);
```

Comment: When I try this is continuously keeps opening a window, one after the other after the other and doesn't stop

Comment: Isn't it triggered from a button press? I.e. this should be in your buttons onclick event.

Answer (score 1):

[`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) needs a URI as the first parameter. Leaving it empty (in your first example) seems to default to `about:blank`, but the string from your second example, `'window.parent.getElementById("printPage")'`, is really not a valid url.

If you want the url of the current window, [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) can be used:

```
 window.open(window.location,'','width=640,height=480,resizeable,scrollbars');
```

You seem to try to get some element's href or src attribute from the parent frame. You need to code that, a string of code won't be evaluated. Use something like

```
 var url = window.parent.getElementById("printPage").src; // I'm guessing that
  // "printpage" is a (i)frame
 window.open(url, '','width=640,height=480,resizeable,scrollbars');
```

instead.

Comment: When I try this is continuously keeps opening a window, one after the other after the other and doesn't stop

Comment: Then your button's click listener is not assigned right. You'll need to show us all of your code.

Comment: It does, but you will need to execute it. Or do you say it throws an error? Then what error does it throw?